# Is following conversion from extensive games to normal form correct?

Tags: proof-verification, game-theory

I studied converson from extensive form games to normal form games from following pdf - http://www.sfu.ca/~shihenl/302/Strategies%20Memo.pdf

So i tried to convert following game(source credit  - http://www.pitt.edu/~rteper/Teaching/econ1200/PS3SOL.pdf)

[image]

I converted to following form -

[image]

Is it correct ? I am thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your normal form is not correct.

It doesn't reflect the fact that Player $2$ gets to see the choice made by Player $1$ before deciding whether to accept or reject.

For each of the $3$ options for Player $1$, there are $2$ options for Player $2$, so Player $2$ has $2^3=8$ distinct strategies.

Thus, the normal form is a $3{\times}{8}$ matrix, not a $3{\times}{2}$ matrix.

**Note:**$\;$The pdf in the link you provided shows the correct $3{\times}{8}$ matrix.

Comment: This answer cleared lot of my doubts . So what i can conclude from your answer is   - To convert extensive to normal form  we need to consider the decision of other player if (s)he has played before me.